# System / Service Host processes constantly using disk

Tags: windows-8.1, task-manager

I built my own computer, and cleanly installed a copy of Windows 8.1
It runs smoothly usually, but at times, two processes are hogging up resources.

System and the service host (local system). Sometimes the antimalware service executable as well.
[image]

This is a new computer with barely anything on it. What causes this and how can I stop it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows *Task Manager*, even on the *Details* tab, does not break out separate processes running under the supervision of *System*. Use MS SysInternals' *Process Explorer* to see the full tree:

[image: Process Explorer]

In this case, hardware interrupts and SMSS (Session Manager Subsystem, manages session) are shown These are essential for Windows, but one of the sessions in SMSS is probably that of the antimalware suite (Windows *Defender* or third-part app).

The [*Antimalware Service Executable*, therefore, is responsible for the issue](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_8-performance/can-one-prevent-antimalware-executable-to-start/14d43f26-c682-4b3d-80b6-59ae754b8649?auth=1). Here are some things to do:

1. Be patient -- this is a brand-new system, and the antimalware suite needs to scan all disks at least once. After the initial full scan, resource usage should drop.
2. If it does *not* get better, then use a different antimalware suite. [Avast!](https://www.avast.com/en-us/index#compare-home), [Norton](http://buy-static.norton.com/norton/ps/bb/1up_ns_us_en_avg_tw_nbfr.html?om_sem_cid=hho_sem_sy:us:ggl:en:e%7Ckw0000006778%7C71939344396%7Cc&country=US), [Kaspersky](http://usa.kaspersky.com/downloads/) and other choices are available, often in both free and paid versions. **Be sure to run only one antivirus at a time**, or conflicts will slow the system greatly. If installing antimalware does not automatically disable *Defender*, do so manually.

**Do not run without antimalware,** though that *would* speed up your system, until it is destroyed by malware.